# No puedo mostrar un placeholder en un select dinamico laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravelcollective

Mi problema es que si le coloco el placeholder entonces el id de años me deja de funcionar y ya no me activa el evento que tengo no se como resolverlo

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('ano', 'Año:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
     <div class="col-lg-10">
         {!! Form::select('ano',$anos_consulta,['id'=>'anos'],[ 'placeholder' => '- Select Años -']) !!}
     </div>
 </div>
 <br><br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('gerencia', 'Gerencia:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        {{Form::select('gerencia',['required'=>'required'],['id'=>'gerencia'])}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿El id deja de funcionar? Nunca he visto algo así... ¿a qué te refieres?

Comment: ['id'=>'anos']  este que es para que me tome una funcion de javascript el cual me genera un evento que al seleccionar años me tire todas las gerencias siguientes

Answer (score 1):

Si nos regimos por el código de Laravel Collective del select, el cual vemos a continuación, todos los atributos deben ir agrupados en un solo parámetro, en este caso un array:

```
/**
 * Create a select box field.
 *
 * @param  string $name
 * @param  array  $list
 * @param  string|bool $selected
 * @param  array  $selectAttributes
 * @param  array  $optionsAttributes
 * @param  array  $optgroupsAttributes
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
 */
public function select(
    $name,
    $list = [],
    $selected = null,
    array $selectAttributes = [],
    array $optionsAttributes = [],
    array $optgroupsAttributes = []
) {

    // ...

}
```

En ese orden de ideas, y siendo estrictos, sería algo así:

```
{!! Form::select('ano', $anos_consulta, null, ['id'=>'anos', 'placeholder' => '- Select Años -']) !!}
```

---

Por cierto, no existe algo así como que el id deje de funcionar, si el atributo está, el id cumple su función, a menos que lo elimines del DOM o algo así.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio mucho

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirvió y/o te solucionó el problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: una consulta por que el siguiente input que es dinamico no me funciona si no le coloco por ejemplo  un parametro como ser $anos_consulta por que si lo dejo en blando y le coloco null me tira un error

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres con "input dinámico"